# How to add more value to a single array in the same function?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object, web

When I try the following code, I get just the first output. I wanted to append all the outputs to the array  `self::$results`  so that the same function will return that array, but after running the script, the function returns the array but only the first output. That means, it appended only the the first output.

```
<?php

/**
* @author Ewoenam
 * @copyright 2014
 * 
 * @odj class book
 */

class book
{
    /**
     * @array static $alpha; holds array of accepted words
     */
    public static $alpha = array();
    /**
     * @array static $result; holds array of correct answers
     */
    public static $results;
    /**
     * @string protected $word; parametr
     */
    protected $word;
    /**
     * @var static $alpha; holder of class instance getter
     * returns self::getInstance
     */
    public static $init;

    /**
     * @method static getInstance(); class instance getter
     * returns self();
     */

    function __construct()
    {
       self::$alpha = array('love','life','health','power','money','God'); 
    } 

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$init === null)
        {
            self::$init = new self();
            return self::$init;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @method static check()
     * takes 1 param; self::$word
     * returns bool
     */
    public static function check($word)
    {

        for($i=0;$i<=count(self::$alpha)-1;$i++)
        {
            if(similar_text($word,self::$alpha[$i]) === strlen($word))
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
    }





    /**
     * @method static result()
     * takes 1 param; self::check()
     * returns bool
     */
    public static function result($bool)
    {
        if($bool === true)
        {
            return 'correct';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'wrong';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @method static getter()
     * takes 1 param; array of words to be searched
     * returns array self::$results
     */
    public static function getter($array)
    {
        self::$results = array();


        for($i = 0;$i<=count($array)-1;$i++)
        {


            // i want to add more thn one answers to to $result array but i get only the first answer.
            //how do i ddo it? 
            self::$results[] = self::result(book::check($array[$i]));

            return self::$results;
        }
    }

}




$array = array('love','ama','kofi','money','health','God');
print_r(book::getInstance()->getter($array));
var_dump(book::check('love')) ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning from `$getter` inside the loop, so it returns after adding the first element. You should finish the loop and then return:

```
public static function getter($array)
{
    self::$results = array();
    for($i = 0;$i<=count($array)-1;$i++)
    {
        self::$results[] = self::result(book::check($array[$i]));
    }
    return self::$results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your `return` in the for loop.  That's why when it goes through the first time, it returns the function right there instead of continuing the loop.

Change your function to this and it will work how you want it to:

```
/**
 * @method static getter()
 * takes 1 param; array of words to be searched
 * returns array self::$results
 */
public static function getter($array)
{
    self::$results = array();


    for($i = 0;$i<=count($array)-1;$i++)
    {


        // i want to add more thn one answers to to $result array but i get only the first answer.
        //how do i ddo it? 
        self::$results[] = self::result(book::check($array[$i]));
    }

    return self::$results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. it works. You know, those are common things we the novice lack. thanks a lot.